# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found. in jupyter tried almost all but didnt work

Tags: pip

Code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
```

Error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import cv2
      3 import os
      4 import random

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
```

tried:

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

`pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl (64-bit version)`

I'm using anaconda nothing works struggling for a week